# Getting the transform class property of an element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make two events depends on a scale property of a menu. So this is my `div`:

```
<div class="starting-point">
    <span class="" style="transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1); height: 2760.56px; width: 2760.56px; top: -1380.28px; left: -1380.28px;"></span>
</div>
```

How can I get the `transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1)` into a variable? Sometimes the values are `scaleX(0) scaleY(0)` and I want to perform different actions depending on these values.

I assigned `dddd` class to that span and I tried this, but there is no scale or something useful in the results.

```
var style = getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName('dddd')[0])
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var style = getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName('dddd')[0], null);

console.log(style.getPropertyValue('transform'));
```

**Edit 1:**

If you prefer not to add the class, you can change your code like this:

```
var style = getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.starting-point span'), null);

console.log(style.getPropertyValue('transform'));
```

**Edit 2:**

You can change it to use jQuery selector as well:

```
var style = getComputedStyle($('.starting-point span')[0], null);

console.log(style.getPropertyValue('transform'));
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for, thanks.
But how about if i don't assign any class name to that span? how to get it ? div children are undefined

Comment: You can change your selector to something like this: `document.querySelector('.starting-point span')`

Comment: Glad this helped!!

Comment: Yes, that method is not a DOM or jQuery method. You can try this instead: `getComputedStyle($('.starting-point span')[0], null).getPropertyValue('transform') ;`

Comment: Edit 2 is exactly what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you are adding jquery tag it is cleaner if you used its APIs

```
var style = $('.starting-point span').attr('style').split(';')[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a more generic method by using regular expressions.

```
var matrix = $('.selector').css('transform');
var values = matrix.match(/-?[\d\.]+/g);
```

This will get all your transform properties you could then get a specific property based on your index value. Such as:

```
console.log(values[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

NB: transform_target here for me is the scale;

```
var variable = $('.classTarget').css('transform','transform_target')[array index]
var newVariable = varaible.style.transform.match(/(-?[0-9\.]+)/g)[array index you want]

console.log(newVariable)
```